# Restrict access to trash, only admin

Tags: permissions, content-restriction, customization, trash, user-access

I'm new in WordPress. I have to restrict access to the Trash for all users except the administrator. All users CAN move to the Trash, but only admin can delete permanently or restored.

I do not know php well, if there is some magical plug or another easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to deny access to trash page in admin. To show trash, the `'post_status'` argument for main query must be 'trash', so you can check that and redirect if current user is not an administrator:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'deny_trash_access' );

function deny_trash_access( $query ) {
  // nothing to do if not in admin or if user is an admin
  if (
    ! is_admin()
    || ! $query->is_main_query()
    || current_user_can( 'remove_users' )
  ) return; 
  $status = $query->get( 'post_status' );
  if (
    $status === 'trash'
    || ( is_array( $status ) && in_array( 'trash', $status, true ) )
  ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( admin_url() );
    exit();
  }
}
```

However, that not prevent users to restore or delete permanently posts.

That can be done using ['wp_insert_post_data'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter, and if in current post data the post status is "trash", and a user try to change it, you can abort the editing by forcing `'post_status'` to be "trash":

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'prevent_trash_status_change', 999, 2 );

function prevent_trash_status_change( $data, $postarr ) {
  if ( ! isset( $postarr['ID'] ) || empty( $postarr['ID'] ) ) return $data;
  if ( current_user_can( 'remove_users' ) ) return $data; // admin can edit trash
  // get the post how it is before the update
  $old = get_post( $postarr['ID'] );
  // if post is trashed, force to be trashed also after the update
  if ( $old->post_status === 'draft' ) { 
    $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
  } 
  return $data;
}
```

Put this 2 code snippets in your function.php or in a plugin file and you are done.

**Edit:** This is an old post, for anybody reading this today, the solution above does not work (any more?). Users can still delete from trash, and publishing drafts doesn't work reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very helpfull. But I still don't understand how I do somethink like that for media